# Linux: huge files vs huge number of files

Tags: linux, performance, amazon-web-services, file-io

I am writing software in C, on Linux running on AWS, that has to handle 240  terabytes of data, in 72 million files.

The data will be spread across 24 or more nodes, so there will only be 10 terabytes on each node, and 3 million files per node.

Because I have to append data to each of these three million files every 60 seconds, the easiest and fastest thing to do would to be able to keep each of these files open at one time.

I can't store the data in a database, because the performance in reading/writing the data will be too slow.  I need to be able to read the data back very quickly.

My questions:

1) is it even possible to keep open 3 million files

2) if it is possible, how much memory would it consume

3) if it is possible, would performance be terrible

4) if it is not possible, I will need to combine all of the individual files into a couple of dozen large files.  Is there a maximum file size in Linux?

5) if it is not possible, what technique should I use to append data every 60 seconds, and keep track of it?

Comment: "I can't store the data in a database, because the performance in reading/writing the data will be too slow" - what do you base that on?

Comment: Design your software so you can easily use distributed file systems, that way it'll be scalable. Increasing your throughput would just mean link another server with it. I guess the only way to know if your server can handle the datastream is to try it I guess.

Comment: @Mitch, I am basing that on it is a huge competitive point to read back the data as fast as possible.  So anything other than raw read/writes to disk will put us at a disadvantage vs our competitors.

Comment: @ShellFish, Each file is about 5MB.  With a distributed file system, what is a reasonable number of files I could expect each server to be able to handle?  I can't find anything on the internet that discusses this.  Could a high performance handle 5,000 files or 500,000 files?

Comment: @user994179 I've heard of some servers dealing with 100k file handles. This info could be very outdated but I've heard it's something like 1 megabyte per one hundred file handles on Linux. So 3 mil would require about 30 gigabytes of RAM if that's the case (but only for the file descriptors). I think a bigger concern if you're trying to compete with commercial databases is disk seek times given the potential fragmentation overhead of dealing with so many separate files. At the very least, you might want some really nice SSDs if you organize data this way.

Comment: About file size limits if you choose to aggregate the data into fewer files, it depends on the file system used by the partition. Perhaps a reasonably safe lowest-common denominator kind of assumption is 2^32 (4 gigabytes) though it could easily be a lot larger for your beefy setup. For performance-critical concerns, I think you'd do better not to just group data arbitrarily into fewer files with that kind of scale, but to try to identify what data would be accessed together to reduce seek times and possibly get some temporal/spatial locality with the way you're caching to memory.

Comment: How much data will you append to each file every 60 seconds?

Comment: @Ike, yes everything is on SSDs.  And the bulk of the initial file writes are all done sequentially, so reads are also sequential; random seeks are not a huge problem on SSDs, but it has been proven that sequential reads even on an SSD are faster than not.

Comment: @user994179: on a properly sized and configured database (SSD IO susbsystem)  reads and writes can be sub millisecond

Comment: 270TB per month works out at ~$9k per month. Quite a lot! http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a very coarse description of an architecture that can work for your problem, assuming that the maximum number of file descriptors is irrelevant when you have enough instances.

First, take a look at this:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elastic-file-system-shared-file-storage-for-amazon-ec2/

https://aws.amazon.com/efs/

EFS provides a shared storage that you can mount as a filesystem.

You can store ALL your files in a single storage unit of EFS. Then, you will need a set of N worker-machines running at full capacity of filehandlers. You can then use a Redis queue to distribute the updates. Each worker has to dequeue a set of updates from Redis, and then will open necessary files and perform the updates.

Again: the maximum number of open filehandlers will not be a problem, because if you hit a maximum, you only need to increase the number of worker machines until you achieve the performance you need.

This is scalable, though I'm not sure if this is the cheapest way to solve your problem.

Comment: To answer your earlier question, every 60 seconds we are appending a tiny amount of data, less than 1k to each file.

Comment: Wow, EFS sounds ideal.  Looks like this was tailor made for our needs.